# setState not updating state on initial submit, only on subsequent submits

Tags: reactjs, async-await, react-hooks

I'm trying to use session storage to set some data, It doesn't work the first time, but works the second time.

```
  const login = async (email, password) => {
    try {
        const user = await loginUser({
          variables: {
            email,
            password
          }
        });

        const { userId, token, expiresIn } = user.data.loginUser;

        setUserData({
          token: token,
          userId: userId,
          expiresIn: expiresIn
        })

        sessionStorage.setItem('interdevs-data', JSON.stringify({ 
          "token": userData.token, 
          "userId": userData.userId, 
          "expiresIn": userData.expiresIn 
        }));
    } catch(err) {
      setLoginErr(err);
    };
  };
```

I'm expecting it to setState on initial submit, but it's okay setting it when I click submit again

Comment: Hi ryan, just wrote you a solution, let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`useState` in `React Hook` also is `asynchronous` like `this.setState` in `React Component`.

So, you can try:

```
const login = async (email, password) => {
    try {
        const user = await loginUser({
          variables: {
            email,
            password
          }
        });

        const { userId, token, expiresIn } = user.data.loginUser;

        // setUserData({
        //   token: token,
        //   userId: userId,
        //   expiresIn: expiresIn
        // })
        // userData here not yet updated
        sessionStorage.setItem('interdevs-data', JSON.stringify({ 
          "token": token, 
          "userId": userId, 
          "expiresIn": expiresIn 
        }));
        // In your case, you can direct access to user.data.loginUser. Don't need use setUserData
    } catch(err) {
      setLoginErr(err);
    };
  };
```

Or if you still want use `setUserData`, try apply `useEffect` like:

```
const login = async (email, password) => {
    try {
        const user = await loginUser({
          variables: {
            email,
            password
          }
        });
        const { userId, token, expiresIn } = user.data.loginUser;
        setUserData({
           token: token,
           userId: userId,
           expiresIn: expiresIn
        })
    } catch(err) {
      setLoginErr(err);
    };
  };

useEffect(() => {
    sessionStorage.setItem('interdevs-data', JSON.stringify({ 
          "token": userData.token, 
          "userId": userData.userId, 
          "expiresIn": userData.expiresIn 
        }));
}, [userData])
```

Answer (score 1):

The `setUserData()` method is asynchronous, which means there's nothing stopping the code written after it from executing before its own logic has completed. This is true for all state-updating methods.

What's likely happening is that the `sessionStorage.setItem()` block runs before you've completely updated the state in the previous block. So there's nothing to save in localStorage the first-time around. But on subsequent attempts the state is updated with the token/user-info from the previous update.

There's a couple ways of resolving this:

1) Is to just update the local-storage with the variables you created instead of waiting for state to finish:

```
  const login = async (email, password) => {
    try {
        const user = await loginUser({
          variables: {
            email,
            password
          }
        });

        const { userId, token, expiresIn } = user.data.loginUser;

        setUserData({
          token: token,
          userId: userId,
          expiresIn: expiresIn
        })

        sessionStorage.setItem('interdevs-data', JSON.stringify({ 
          "token": token, 
          "userId": userId, 
          "expiresIn": expiresIn 
        }));
    } catch(err) {
      setLoginErr(err);
    };
  };
```

2) Employ `useEffect()` to update localStorage when state-changes.

```
  useEffect(() => {
        sessionStorage.setItem('interdevs-data', JSON.stringify({ 
          "token": userData.token, 
          "userId": userData.userId, 
          "expiresIn": userData.expiresIn 
        }));
  }, [user]) //swap user with whatever you called your state

  const login = async (email, password) => {
    try {
        const user = await loginUser({
          variables: {
            email,
            password
          }
        });

        const { userId, token, expiresIn } = user.data.loginUser;

        setUserData({
          token: token,
          userId: userId,
          expiresIn: expiresIn
        })

    } catch(err) {
      setLoginErr(err);
    };
  };
```